# Upgrading from FPDF 1.53 to 1.6--any problems?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

As I think most people know already, or if you don't, [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) released a new version, 1.6 this past August after almost 4 years without a release. I'm wondering if anyone has had any problems upgrading from 1.53 to 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any problems with my scripts updating to 1.6, and the new version fixes an issue I had with IE, so I'm satisfied with this update.